# DNS config to point subdomain to another vhost

Tags: dns, nginx

I have a digital ocean droplet where I have one server block serving a static homepage and another server block serving a meteor.js application. I'd like to point a subdomain at the meteor application, but at present the subdomain is loading the main static page.

my current DNS configuration is:

```
A        @    1.2.3.4
CNAME    www  mydomain.com.
CNAME    *    mydomain.com.
NS       ns1.digitalocean.com.
...
```

I thought by adding another CNAME it would point to my meteor application...

```
CNAME    foo   mydomain.com.
```

but when I visit foo.mydomain.com I get the main root domain page.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another A record 'foo.mydomain.com' and point it to your second server with meteor.js application.

Take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/3-things-you-should-know-about-dns.html) for more information and examples of DNS records usage.